# how to transfer contacts from lumia 635 to computer?

Tags: transfer

how to transfer contacts from lumia 635 to computer?
I have outlook 2013 on my windows 8 computer

Answer (score 1):

Generally, contacts are not stored *only* on your phone, and your phone will sync with the online services you've set up - So, if you've associated a Hotmail (aka. Outlook.com) account, then these *can* be stored there; Similarly, You can use a Gmail account or a corporate Exchange account.

You can then connect Outlook (or the People app in Windows 8, 8.1 and 10) on your desktop PC up to the same services to share the same address book(s). The [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) website if you need specific help for the desktop side of connecting to those same online services.